# Typescript enum switch going to default instead of proper case

Tags: enums, switch-statement, typescript

I have the following enum:

```
enum EditMode {
    View = 0,
    Edit = 1,
    Delete = 2
}
```

Let's assume I have a variable of the enum type

```
var editMode = EditMode.Edit;
```

Why does the following code not work (goes straight to default)?

```
switch (editMode) {
    case EditMode.Delete:
        // ...
        break;
    case EditMode.Edit:
        // ...
        break;
    default:
        // ...
        break;
}
```

Comment: This code works in the TypeScript Playground. Are you sure your scripts are loading in the correct order?

Comment: I can also confirm it works in the Playground.

Comment: yes it does, it seems the issue is not the code itself. for some reason my code assigns not a number behind the enum but the string associated with the number eg istead of 1 (Edit) "1". why i can't understand.

Comment: Replace it with if/else and it should work. There are a bunch of typing issues/features in TypeScript. Eg. that one - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8618

Comment: Actually this code is NOT working in the Typescript playground... editmode DELETE is not comparable to editmode EDIT

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have found why this happens: somewhere in the code there is a activation function (I am using durandal) which passes this enum as a string (the function has the parameter marked as a enum but still it is a string). This is why my switch statement fails.

I simply converted the value to a number and now everything works as expected.

Comment: This was the problem for me as well. My constructor had a parameter of type Enum, but an outside caller was passing a string. I changed the constructor parameter to be of type string, and used EnumType[parameter] to convert it to the enum.

Answer (score 119):

I also had this problem.  Easy way to get around it: add a `+` sign before your variable in the switch, i.e.

```
switch (+editMode) {
    case EditMode.Delete:
        ...
        break;
    case EditMode.Edit:
        ...
        break;
    default:
        ...
        break;
    }
```

Comment: This seems the only way to fix the typescript glitch / bug.

Comment: So the + will change it to a number, and that seems to work. I think this does not seem like a great solution.  I also tried assigning the first item to 0 in my enum and it did not help. Seems like a bug.

Comment: + is a hack that coerces it to a number.  My answer below is correct based on modern Typescript version.

Answer (score 21):

The issue here has to do with typescript's [(numeric) literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types). When you do this assignment:

```js
var editMode = EditMode.Edit
```

TypeScript evaluates the type as:

```js
var editMode: 1 = EditMode.Edit
```

Now, when you compare a value that typescript knows *must* be `1` (`EditMode.Edit`) to a value that it knows *must* be `0` (`EditMode.View`), it sees all this as a type-safety violation. If the variable `editMode` weren't an `enum`, typescript would merely complain, but since it's an `enum`, which doesn't really exist in javascript, typescript gets to control the transpilation in such a way that it actually throws an error. 
So you have 2 options. So you can either coerce `editMode` to be a `number` or to be an `EditMode` (i.e. any of the values `EditMode` is permitted to be, not just the one assigned to `editMode` the variable). 
Personally, I prefer to coerce it to be an `EditMode`, because it feels more type-safe.
To go the number route, you can do the following, which was previously mentioned:

```js
switch(+editMode)
```

To go the `EditMode` route (which I recommend), you can pass it to a function as was mentioned, but sometimes it's a little cleaner to not write a function. If that's the case here, then you can again coerce the type in the `switch` statement:

```js
switch(editMode as EditMode)
```

Do whichever you prefer, but I just like the clarity of explicitly saying "this variable is being treated as an `EditMode`" as opposed to "this variable is supposed to actually be a `number`, not an `Enum`".

Answer (score 15):

Change your EditMode enum definition to:

```
enum EditMode {
    View = "View",
    Edit = "Edit",
    Delete = "Delete"
}
```

Comment: This worked for me better than the integer-based solutions, because my objects were coming in from a REST service that served a JSON where the enum values where text values, thus I couldn't assign numbers to them or I would break the serialization/deserialization process.

Comment: This is proper answer

Answer (score 12):

TypeScript version **3.7.5**

this code worked for me

```
enum Seasons {
    Winter,
    Spring,
    Summer,
    Autum
  }

switch (+Seasons.Winter) {
    case Seasons.Winter:
        console.log('weather is cold');
        break;
    case Seasons.Spring:
        console.log('weather is spring');
        break;
    case Seasons.Summer:
        console.log('weather is summer');
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

[image: visual studio code: seasons]

or you can declare a constant and use as param for switch  statement

```
const season: Seasons = Seasons.Winter
switch (+season) {
    case Seasons.Winter:
        console.log('weather is cold');
        break;
    case Seasons.Spring:
        console.log('weather is spring');
        break;
    case Seasons.Summer:
        console.log('weather is summer');
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

[image]

Comment: it doesn't work without the plus ('+'). how come it solves the problem?

Comment: d***, life saver. any documentation?

Answer (score 3):

In case somebody else ends up here and the above options don't seem to be the issue, double-check that all of your switch statements are breaking/returning!  The Typescript compiler is smart enough to see that if your `case` cascades through to another one, the value you're comparing on may never hit the case you expect.

```
let handlerName;

switch(method){
  case 'create':
    handlerName = 'createHandler';
    break;
  case 'update';
    handlerName = 'updateHandler';
    // Here is where the forgotten break would go
  default:
    throw new Error('Unrecognized Method');
}

switch(handlerName){
  case 'createHandler':
    ...
    break;
  case 'updateHandler':
    // You will see an error on this case because
    // the compiler knows that execution will never
    // arrive here with handler === 'updateHandler'
  default:
    throw new Error('Unrecognized Handler');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `//@ts-ignore` suppress you can do:

```
//@ts-ignore
switch (EditMode[editMode] as EditMode) {
    case EditMode.Delete:
        ...
        break;
    case EditMode.Edit:
        ...
        break;
    default:
        ...
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this works, it's unwise to @ts-ignore all your problems away. TS is there to help you write type-safe code to avoid headache down the line. Though ignore this advice if TS itself has a bug and you have to rely on it to deploy.

Answer (score 1):

If the enum is defined in a separate typescript file, ensure it's marked with "export" and that you import it correctly at the top of the typescript file you're referencing it in.

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this.

```
const enum OperationsType{
    CREATE="CREATE",
    DELETE="DELETE",
    UPDATE="UPDATE"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Int Enum

```
    enum Sizes {
      Small,
      Medium,
    }
    
    switch (Number(Sizes.Small)) {
      case Sizes.Small:
       

 // ️ this runs
    console.log('size is S');
    break;
  case Sizes.Medium:
    console.log('size is M');
    break;

  default:
    console.log(`non-existent size: ${Sizes.Small}`);
    break;
}
```

> String Enum

```
enum Sizes {
      Small = 'S',
      Medium = 'M',
    }
    
    switch (String(Sizes.Small)) {
      case Sizes.Small:
        console.log('size is S');
        break;
      case Sizes.Medium:
        console.log('size is M');
        break;
    
      default:
        console.log(`non-existent size: ${Sizes.Small}`);
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Declare your enum using `const`:

```
const enum EditMode {
    View = 0,
    Edit = 1,
    Delete = 2
}
```

Comment: This does not fix it for me.

Comment: This will work on versions 3.0 and older but not on newer versions.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had the switch inside a condition, which was coercing the enum into a value:

```
enum A {
    VAL_A,
    VAL_B,
    VAL_C
}
interface ia {
    maybe?: A
}
const o: ia = {maybe: 0}
if(o.maybe){ //<-- o.maybe is not falsey (thus, is not 0)
    switch(o.maybe) {
        case A.VAL_A: //<-- Error! we know that o.maybe is not 0. Its VAL_B | VAL_C
        break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you use the `switch` expression in a function with typed parameter, this works as expected.

Example:

```
enum EditMode {
    View,
    Edit,
    Delete,
}

function testSwitch(editMode: EditMode) {
    switch(editMode) {
        case EditMode.Delete:
            console.log("delete");
            break;
        case EditMode.Edit:
            console.log("edit");
            break;
        default:
            console.log("default");
            break;
    }
}

testSwitch(EditMode.Edit)
```

will compile  and output `edit`

Comment: This will work on version 3.0 in typescript but not on later version.